# Python - How to check if multiple words in string in a list

Tags: python, string, list, data-analysis

I have this code:

```
intents = ['hello world', 'random string']

phrase = input(Enter your message: )

if phrase in intents:
    print('Found')
```

How can I check if phrase in intents without typing the exact strings in intents, If it's only one word it's easy but multiple words it's not working like that:

```
Enter your message: hello world this python
>>> Found
```

Comment: It's not clear about your *logic* here - the *phrase* has 4 words, but it only matches *2* words in the *intents*? So  what's the exact logic/requirement? - What is the definition of ```multiple words```?

Comment: I can't understand. I think that phrase **isn't** in intents, and I don't think it's in any of the elements of the list, either. What reasoning should the code apply?  Talk us through it, step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You got the logic backwards.

```py
for intent in intents:
    if intent in phrase:
        print('Found')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

For this example you can just switch your logic around
instead of checking for `phrase` in `intents`, check if *`intents` in `phrase`*

ie:

```
intents = ['hello world', 'random string']

phrase = input(Enter your message: )

for intent in intents:
  if intent in phrase:
    return True
```

this is assuming the input is always larger than the `intent`,

you could add a check for the length

basically check if the smaller str is in the larger one, not the other way around.

I think you could also do some fancy trickery with `any`

like

```
is_in = any([i in phrase for i in intents] + [j in intents for j in phrase])
```